# JAVA Springboot & IBM MQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq, autowired

I am having a spring boot rest service application which needs to send data to IBM MQ in error scenarios . I have my MQ details defined in the application.properties of my spring boot application like below :

application.properties :

```
project:
  mq:
    host: myhost.com
    port: 1437
    queue-manager: abcdef
    channel: abc.def.02
    queueTo: abc.01
    username: user
    password: pass
    receive-timeout: 2000
```

I have packaged all my MQ Connectivity handling code in a seperate MQConnector jar so that I can reuse that jar from other services as well.

My question is , How do I pass the MQ values from application.properties of spring boot service application to the MQConnector jar . Is it possible to autowire and read values in the MQConnector jar with data from spring boot service application ?

```
public class Sender< T > implements ISender< T >
{
 @Value( "${project.mq.queueTo}" )
 private String queue;
 ...
}
```

The project.mq.queueTo should refer the mq.queueTo inforamtion from the application.properties file of spring boot service application.

Appreciate your guidance on this. Thank you.

Comment: Annotate it as a Bean and give it ConfigurationProperties to get the queue connection parameters.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out and keep you posted..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Component annotation at class level in the jar. Then you can directly @Autowire this class anywhere.